# "Network is unreacheable" but internet is working

Tags: networking

```
 Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable.
```

I contacted the bit-bucket support team, but they didn't have a solution for me.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe your DNS server isn't working ? Try adding `8.8.8.8` as an additional DNS server in the network configuration. Can you ping hosts other than bitbucket, e.g.  `google.com` ?

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution from [the Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html):

```
sudo ufw allow 443
```